# How to select text property in mx:DateField

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml

I want to manually select the text inside the "textInput" box of Datefield.
How can i do that? Since only TextInput components have "selectAll()" method which selects the whole string inside the insertion box.

I've looked everywhere and never found.

I've tried this

```
var text_input:mx.controls.TextInput = date_field.mx_internal::getTextInput();                  
text_input.setSelection(0, text_input.length);
text_input.setFocus();
```

but it did not work, "text_input.text" was empty. So I guess its another component who displays the string in the box of the Datefield. I fill the Datefield with the selectedDate property.

```
dateField.selectedDate = date;
```

-------------Edit

It worked. All I had to do was find the right way to put that code. When you use selectedDate before the creationComplete and triggers of the DateField it don't actually sets the text_input. You have to wait it to fully complete it's trigger events in order to use the text_input. So, I used value_commit trigger to select the text after I setted the selectedDate. Here it is:

```
protected function cmpDateFault_valueCommitHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            if(isSelect){

                var text_input:mx.controls.TextInput = cmpDateFault_valueCommitHandler.mx_internal::getTextInput();                  
                text_input.setSelection(0, text_input.length);
                text_input.setFocus();

                isSelect = false;
            }
        }
```

the "isSelect" is a trick I used to make the value_commit only work in the first time, which was what I wanted. I setted the isSelected before the fully creation and triggers were completed on other mxml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using `mx.core.mx_internal` like this :

```
var text_input:mx.controls.TextInput = date_field.mx_internal::getTextInput();                  
    text_input.setSelection(0, text_input.length);
    text_input.setFocus();
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Before putting my answer, I tested it and it worked fine. How did you used it ?

Comment: I see, it worked with you. I don't know why it struggles with me.

Comment: I'm using Flex Builder 4.6, you?

Comment: I'm using Flash Builder 4.5 with Flex 4.5.